# How to match two arrays, with alternate spelling option?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays that I want to find the intersection for, however I also have an alternate spelling field, that should act as an extra matching pattern.

Here is an example of the genres array

```
const genres = 
    { id: 20, name: 'Hip-Hop', alt_spelling: [ 'Hip Hop', 'HipHop' ] },
    { id: 21, name: 'House', alt_spelling: [ 'Deep House', 'Acid' ]},
    { id: 22, name: 'Alternative', alt_spelling: [] },
    { id: 23, name: 'Dance', alt_spelling: ["Techno"] }

const genreNames = genres.map((genre) => genre.name.toLowerCase())

const tags = ["Alternative", "Deep House", "Techno"]
```

Currently the following block of code works and will return ["Alternative"], however I'd like it to also match the alt_spellings, so should return the object IDs but with the alt_spelling matched, so should return [21, 22, 23], as Deep House and Techno would match the alternate spellings.

```
  const matchedGenres = tags?.filter((element) =>
    genreNames.includes(element.toLowerCase()),
  )
```

Any help here would be great :)
Thanks

Comment: To do this right, it's gonna be an implementation of statistical analysis where you account for misspellings too. I would imaging you would want to do some string comparisons at the specific letter indexes and accept matches of, let's say 80% or more. In terms of exact matching alt_spelling it might be easiest to rename that property/field to `spellings` to include the correct spelling also so you don't have to join anything before iterating thru the possibilities. Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const genres = [{ id: 20, name: 'Hip-Hop', alt_spelling: ['Hip Hop', 'HipHop'] },{ id: 21, name: 'House', alt_spelling: ['Deep House', 'Acid'] },{ id: 22, name: 'Alternative', alt_spelling: [] },{ id: 23, name: 'Dance', alt_spelling: ['Techno'] },]

const genresHash = genres.reduce(
  (acc, { id, name, alt_spelling }) => ((acc[id] ??= [name, ...alt_spelling]), acc),
  {}
)

const tags = ['Alternative', 'Deep House', 'Techno']

const matchedGenres = genres.filter((genre) =>
  genresHash[genre.id].some((name) =>
    tags.some((tag) => name.localeCompare(tag, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }) === 0)
  )
)

console.log(matchedGenres)
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Yosvel! I believe it's working however it's just returning the original tags stringed array. ie. ["Alternative","Deep House","Techno"].

Is it possible to make it return the actual matched genres? So [{id: 20..., id:  21...., id: 22...}]?

Comment: @unicorn_surprise Edited answer based on your comment

Comment: I saw you need case sensitive filtering, so improved by using [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)